# Do a 301 redirect if there is no products in the current category

Tags: redirect, seo, magento2, categories

As a part of the SEO optimizations, when a customer go to a category page and if there is no products in the category, can we redirect it to a 301?

Eg: As a part of -ve testing, if we load the category page with a non valid page number, then magento will show the message as "We can't find products matching the selection.". So instead of this i want to either redirect to 301 OR redirect 404 is also fine in this case. Do we have any solution for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the SEO tag states: GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question here first.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution.

1. Create a module
2. Add a plugin for the ListProduct file in di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="redirect_empty_category" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ListProduct"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

3. Create the plugin php class

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Laminas\Http\Response;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class ListProduct
{

    /**
     * @param ResponseInterface $response
     * @param UrlInterface $url
     */
    public function __construct(
        private readonly ResponseInterface $response,
        private readonly UrlInterface $url
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject
     * @param AbstractCollection $result
     *
     * @return AbstractCollection
     */
    public function afterGetLoadedProductCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        AbstractCollection $result
    ): AbstractCollection {
        if ($result->getSize() === 0) {
            $this->response->setRedirect(
                $this->url->getUrl('your-redirect-url'), // change this to the URL you want to redirect to.
                Response::STATUS_CODE_302 // even though this is set to 302, if you decide you can go with 301 as well.
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

This solution is provided by [@ahmad](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/75833/ahmad) Thank you Ahamd.
Full module structure can be found in the original answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368633/5143)